# Is there an easy way to auto-increase a build number in Flutter (web+android+ios)?

Tags: flutter, dart, versioning

In some of our projects we develop Flutter codebase for web, andriod and ios, and in others we have just web.

Is there an easy or built in way in Flutter to cope with auto incremented build numbers (running numbers for each build you do). This is somehow managable in android and ios (androd: clever Gradle scripts), but I haven't found any easy way to do it for web. For us it is likely crucial to have control of build sets there as for the native ones.

If not, (in my mind) there should be more robust app versioning system which where universal for all flawors.

Answer (score 1):

U can change in build, like this:

```
flutter build appbundle --build-name=1.0.0+2 --build-number=3
```

And can use package info plus for show
https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

String appName = packageInfo.appName;
String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
String version = packageInfo.version;
String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```

EDIT.

Please, check this script :
https://github.com/sergiotucano/build_flutter_app

Will update the version automatically.

Comment: I wished for a kind if script raising the build number each time I either ran 'flutter run' or pressed 'play' or 'hot reload' in Android Studio... ? or do theese arguments just that ?

Comment: Roar, I edited the response and Add a link for a script that I created. This script will update the version automatically. It's a first version of script. So... If u see a bug, please, report to me.